# AWS glacier delete job

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-glacier

I have started a retrival job for an archive stored in one of my vaults on 
Glacier AWS.

It turns out that I do not need to resurrect and download that archive any more.
Is there a way to stop and/or delete my Glacier job?

I am using boto and I cannot seem to find a suitable function.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The AWS Glacier service does not provide a way to delete a job.  You can:

- Initiate a job
- Describe a job
- Get the output of a job
- List all of your jobs

The Glacier service manages the jobs associated with an vault.

Comment: That's annoying, but thanks for definitively stating that you can't cancel an ongoing restore operation.

Comment: Here's the source for that information: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/job-operations.html

Comment: how long does the output of the job stay before you cant access it anymore?

Comment: @thepickle - doco says, "After completion, a job will not expire for at least 24 hours"